# MySQL in Python 2.5

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to know how can I handle MySQL in python 2.5. Is there any build in library? Or any small external library?

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/ it is a souerceforge project.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other option? I will have o lot of problems in compiling this on my hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you suggest, you can't build C modules, try using one of the pure Python modules listed [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL). Use `virtualenv` to create your own site-packages directory and `pip` to install it. I have no idea how well any of those work though.

Answer (score 0):

The frequently linked MySQL-Python module is probably the way to go, but [Pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) is also compatible with MySQL, just to give you other options.